# Use of unresolved identifier GethNewTransaction

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, ethereum

Using go-ethereum iOS framework I'm trying to create a new transaction. Using GethNewTransaction i get an error (Use of unresolved identifier GethNewTransaction).

An example is found here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mobile:-Account-management

```
// Create a new account to sign transactions with
var error: NSError?
let signer = try! ks?.newAccount("Signer password")

let to    = GethNewAddressFromHex("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", &error)
let tx    = GethNewTransaction(1, to, GethNewBigInt(0), 
GethNewBigInt(0), GethNewBigInt(0), nil) // Random empty transaction
let chain = GethNewBigInt(1) // Chain identifier of the main net
```

My code:

```
// Create a new account to sign transactions with
var error: NSError?
var signer: GEGethAccount?; try! ks?.newAccount("Signer password", ret0_: &signer)

var to: GEGethAddress?; GEGethNewAddressFromHex("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", &to, &error)
let tx = GethNewTransaction(1, to, GEGethNewBigInt(0), GEGethNewBigInt(0), GEGethNewBigInt(0), nil) // Random empty transaction
let chain = GEGethNewBigInt(1) // Chain identifier of the main net
```

This line is wrong:

```
let tx = GethNewTransaction(1, to, GEGethNewBigInt(0), GEGethNewBigInt(0), GEGethNewBigInt(0), nil) // Random empty transaction
```

How do i write this line to create a new transaction?